# Set the value of an input field bootstrap 4.5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

How would you set the default value of a form input text field in JavaScript?

```
<input type="hidden" id="rolnik_id" name="id_rolnik" value="x">

<script>
    document.getElementById("rolnik_id").setAttribute('value','50');
</script>
```

Comment: what is wrong with this js?

Comment: simply assign value as `value="x"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    document.getElementById("rolnik_id").setAttribute('value','50');
```

with

```
    document.getElementById("rolnik_id").value = 50;
```

Comment: Can you please share peace of code, jsfiddle or codepen link?

Comment: this is part od application, https://pastebin.pl/view/55e3b380

Comment: an this is core view https://pastebin.pl/view/018530af

Comment: Also you are changing (overwrite in if condition) value with jquery `$("#rolnik_id").val('<?=$id_rolnik?>');`

Comment: i delete overvrite $("#rolnik_id").val('<?=$id_rolnik?>');

Comment: and in inspect is value="x" all time

Comment: Before going any further, Hard Refresh first with `CTRL + F5`.